# Importing Creative Commons data dump into MySQL

Tags: support, data-dump

Has anyone got any tools/scripts etc. for getting the data dump into MySQL?

Comment: I have one :( But I'm not sure if I want to release my ugly code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a [script](http://code.google.com/p/geeqe/source/browse/trunk/scripts/load.rb) and [schema](http://code.google.com/p/geeqe/source/browse/trunk/scripts/schema.sql) for mysql that you can use if you are interested. The load script requires Ruby. I also split a tags out into their own table.

Comment: I was wondering this is up to date with the latest data dump?

Comment: will this work for stackexchange dataset? Thank You.

Comment: I know I have used your script in past but don't recall of this error: but I just recently tried and I am getting an error in badges.xml at `<row Id="253861" UserId="74951" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2009-03-08T02:02:32.390" /> : Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08T02:02:32.390' for column 'created' at row 1 (Mysql::Error)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a windows app that will import to MySql,MS Sql and SQLite:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-2000-05-08-sqlite-mysql

Answer (score 0):

See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/importing-data-dump-into-anything-other-than-sql-server) (duplicate) answer asked yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a project that can import all of the latest dumps (as of August 2014) into any relational database that supports JPA/hibernate. It is written in Java, but can also be used from the command line. Prerequisites are Java 8 and Maven.

https://github.com/1123/StackExchangeImporter